# PSQLException: This connection has been closed - Spring Boot + AWS RDS + Postgres

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I am getting `PSQLException: This connection has been closed` when trying to access my Postgres database in AWS RDS. The exception happens randomly (not all the times I run the code) and it's more probable to happen if it takes a while before the execution reaches the code below:

```
@Transactional
public void revokeChanges(ArrayList<Integer> changeIds) {
    jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sqlUpdate,
            new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {
                @Override
                public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
                    ps.setStuff..
                    ...
                }
                @Override
                public int getBatchSize() {
                    return changeIds.size();
                }
            });
    jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sqlInsert,
            new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {
                @Override
                public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
                    ps.setStuff...
                }
                @Override
                public int getBatchSize() {
                    return changeIds.size();
                }
            });
```

Connection Stuff:

`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://my-url:port/dbName?tcpKeepAlive=true&autoReconnect=true`

`spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver`

Relevant POM:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.9.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.3-1102-jdbc41</version>
    </dependency>
```

Stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This connection has been closed.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:296)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:320)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory.getErrorCodes(SQLErrorCodesFactory.java:214)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.setDataSource(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:134)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:97)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcAccessor.getExceptionTranslator(JdbcAccessor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:660)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:673)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(JdbcTemplate.java:989)
    at my.package.DataServiceJdbc.revokeChanges(DataServiceJdbc.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy24.revokeChanges(Unknown Source)
    at my.package.DataExporterS3ToPostgre.exportData(DataExporterS3ToPostgre.java:59)
    at my.package.Application.main(Application.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This connection has been closed.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.checkClosed(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:843)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.getMetaData(Jdbc4Connection.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:126)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:80)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23.getMetaData(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:285)
    ... 29 common frames omitted
```

Comment: As mentioned in my other answer:
[I had exactly the same problem ... I figured out that when doing a long query the same error appears. In my case I called findAll(Iterable ids) and passed a huge list of more than 100'000 ids. Partitioning the list (e.g. using ListUtils from Apache Commons or Google Guava) and calling the findAll() with less ids did the trick.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35582636/3437868)

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the connection is lost between DB and pool. Try to set up removeAbandoned and removeAbandonedTimeout options. For more datails about those options read [JDBC Connection Pool docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#Common_Attributes).