# Heroku Postgres: This connection has been closed

Tags: postgresql, grails, heroku, grails-orm

I developed a small Heroku + Grails + Postreg application. It would work fine somewhat 20 minutes after deployment, after that I always get:

```
 This connection has been closed.. Stacktrace follows: Heroku/myapp
- org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This connection has been closed. Heroku/myapp
- at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.checkClosed(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:837) Heroku/myapp
- at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.getAutoCommit(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:798) Heroku/myapp
- at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi$_methodMissing_closure2.doCall(GormStaticApi.groovy:102) Heroku/myapp
- at com.myapp.WorkspaceController.list(WorkspaceController.groovy:18) Heroku/myapp
- at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:198) Heroku/myapp
- at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63) Heroku/myapp
- at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53) Heroku/myapp
- at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.java:53) Heroku/myapp
- at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.java:62) Heroku/myapp
- at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) Heroku/myapp
- at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) Heroku/myapp
- at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Heroku/myapp
- 2015-08-07 15:11:10,685 [http-nio-20850-exec-5] ERROR spi.SqlExceptionHelper - This connection has been closed. Heroku/myapp
- 2015-08-07 15:11:10,689 [http-nio-20850-exec-5] ERROR spi.SqlExceptionHelper - This connection has been closed. Heroku/myapp
- 2015-08-07 15:11:10,696 [http-nio-20850-exec-5] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver - PSQLException occurred when processing request: [GET] /api/users/21/workspaces Heroku/myapp
- This connection has been closed.. Stacktrace follows: Heroku/myapp
```

Comment: Can you paste your data source settings within grails?

Answer (score 6):

I have resolved it myself by adding this to DataSource.groovy:

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    properties {
       maxActive = -1
       minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=1800000
       timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=1800000
       numTestsPerEvictionRun=3
       testOnBorrow=true
       testWhileIdle=true
       testOnReturn=true
       validationQuery="SELECT 1"
    }
}
```

Comment: Any idea which of these properties actually made the difference?

Comment: I had the same problem in a Spring Boot app (using [DataSource](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/DataSource.html) from Tomcat JDBC), and looks like I got it solved using `setTestOnBorrow(true); setTestWhileIdle(true); setTestOnReturn(true); setValidationQuery("SELECT 1");` ([javadocs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/DataSourceProxy.html#setTestOnBorrow(boolean))). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A combination of @Macchiatow's answer and @Jonik's comment, this is what I used to work, with fewer properties:

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    properties {
        testOnBorrow = true
        testWhileIdle = true
        testOnReturn = true
        validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
    }
    driverClassName = "org.postgresql.Driver"
    dialect = "..."
}
```