# How to connect to heroku postgress database from JDBC?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, database-connection

I use this code 
But can anyone suggest me or guide me to a right document which can give me an example of how to connect to heroku postgress database with JDBC ?

```
    URI dbUri = new URI(System.getenv("DATABASE_URL"));
    String dbUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://" + dbUri.getHost() + 
    dbUri.getPath();
    connectionPool = new BasicDataSource();

    if (dbUri.getUserInfo() != null) {
        connectionPool.setUsername(dbUri.getUserInfo().split(":")[0]);
        connectionPool.setPassword(dbUri.getUserInfo().split(":")[1]);
    }
    connectionPool.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    connectionPool.setUrl(dbUrl);
    connectionPool.setInitialSize(1);

    Connection connection = connectionPool.getConnection();
```

Comment: I have set dependency in my pom.xml for org.postgresql.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connecting to Heroku Postgres from Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33633243/connecting-to-heroku-postgres-from-spring-boot)

Answer (score 1):

See heroku's [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-relational-databases-on-heroku-with-java)

Note:

The `DATABASE_URL` for the Heroku Postgres add-on follows the below convention

```
postgres://<username>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<dbname>
```

However the Postgres JDBC driver uses the following convention:

```
jdbc:postgresql://<host>:<port>/<dbname>?user=<username>&password=<password>
```

Sample code to parse DATABASE_URL into Jdbc format:

```
private static Connection getConnection() throws URISyntaxException, SQLException {
   URI dbUri = new URI(System.getenv("DATABASE_URL"));
   String username = dbUri.getUserInfo().split(":")[0];
   String password = dbUri.getUserInfo().split(":")[1];
   String dbUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://" + dbUri.getHost() + ':' + dbUri.getPort() + dbUri.getPath();

   return DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, username, password);
}
```

Comment: So , i saw that, and i believe problem lies with my DATABASE_URL environment, since when i am trying to get it's value, there is no username/password attached to it. 
May be it is because i haven't set the value of DATABSE_URL anywhere ?
I am getting this error : 
Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.

Comment: make sure there's a DATABASE_URL in your heroku config - `heroku config | grep DATABASE_URL` if there's none, then promote the DB  `heroku pg:promote HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_XXX` where XXX is the color of the DB.