# JDBC Connection Pool: connections are not recycled after DB restart

Tags: java, postgresql, tomcat, jdbc

I added `setMaxActive(8)` on `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PoolProperties`. Every time the DB restarts, the application is unusable because the established connections remain. I get the following error:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This connection has been closed

I've tried using some other settings on the pool to no avail...

Thank you for help!

Comment: Catch that exception and re-create the connection in the pool

Answer (score 1):

Use the `validationQuery` property which will check if the connection is valid before returning the connection.

Ref: [Tomcat 6 JDBC Connection Pool](http://people.apache.org/%7Efhanik/tomcat/jdbc-pool.html)

This property is available on latest tomcat versions.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this link:

> [Postgres connection has been closed error in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29620265/postgres-connection-has-been-closed-error-in-spring-boot)
>
> Very valid question and this problem is usually faced by many. The
>   exception generally occurs, when network connection is lost between
>   pool and database (most of the time due to restart). Looking at the
>   stack trace you have specified, it is quite clear that you are using
>   jdbc pool to get the connection. JDBC pool has options to fine-tune
>   various connection pool settings and log details about whats going on
>   inside pool.
>
> You can refer to to detailed [Apache documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html) on pool
>   configuration to specify abandon timeout
>
> ```
> Check for removeAbandoned, removeAbandonedTimeout, logAbandoned parameters
> ```
>
> Additionally you can make use of additional properties to further
>   tighten the validation
>
> ```
> Use testXXX and validationQuery for connection validity.
> ```

My own $0.02: use these two parameters:

```
validationQuery=<TEST SQL>
testOnBorrow=true
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried using removeAbandoned, that didn't help, I'll try the validationQuery and testOnBorrow.